# How do I create a debuggable build in jenkins using a pom file?

Tags: maven, jenkins, robotium, pom.xml

I am trying to build a robotium apk file that can execute test cases automatically from jenkins and receive the following error:

```
[INFO]   Run started: se.stuff.android.app.test, 7 tests:
[INFO]     Start: se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_A_check_app
[INFO]     End: se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_A_check_app
[INFO]     Start: se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_B_bad_credentials
[INFO]     End: se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_B_bad_credentials
[INFO]     Start: se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_C_Log_in
[INFO]     ERROR:se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_C_Log_in
[INFO]     Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException''. Check device logcat for details
[INFO]     End: se.stuff.android.test.app.APP_Test#test_C_Log_in
[INFO]   Run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
[INFO]   Run ended: 0 ms
[ERROR]   FAILURES!!!
[INFO]   Tests run: 3 (of 7),  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
[INFO] Report file written to /var/lib/hudson/jobs/App_Android_Test/workspace/APP_Test/target/surefire-reports/TEST-localhost_49851_unknown_sdk.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I checked the emulator and seem to be missing the InstrumentationTesRunner. What I have heard is that instrumentation classes are excluded when an application is built for release. My question is therefore, how do I create a debuggable build in jenkins using a pom.xml file and building with maven?

The two first test cases can actually pass with nothing happening since it's supposed to check that everything is ok before start. If it doesn't find potential issues will the test execution just continue.

Comment: There should be a place to put <debug> true </debug> in the build which should fix your issue. I cant remember where exactly but will find out when I have the time.

Comment: I have set the <debug> true </debug> under the maven section in the pom file but it doesn't seem to make any difference.